# how can I "tilt" my laptop for a game

Tags: windows-8, laptop, tablet

I have Windows 8 and therefore I can download games made for a Surface or Windows Phone. Some of these games require that you "tilt" your tablet in order to move to the side. However, I am using a laptop with no rotation sensors whatsoever. Is it still possible to play these games with a keyboard and mouse, or do I need a tablet?

Comment: 'have Windows 8'.  You cannot download games for Windows Phone.  Also, you have to know the difference between Windows 8 and Windows 8 RT.  If it's designed specifically for a tablet, it's generally going to be for RT, and it's not directly available for you- if you're rocking a laptop or desktop.  So, as annoying as it is for most of us, Windows 8 RT != Windows 8/8 Pro != Windows Phone 8.  All three are slightly different platforms, and the same compiled app will not work on more than one.

Comment: "If it's designed specifically for a tablet, it's generally going to be for RT" - Pretty soon there will be far more Surface Pro and variants from other manufacturers than there ever will be RT devices.

Comment: I have Windows 8 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard laptop cannot basically simulate such an event as it simply has no appropriate sensors.
Note that there are these special notebooks where you are able to rotate the display and use it has a "very thick" tablet, then. Those might have one.

However, it is the app developer's job to make his app run everywhere and be usable everywhere. I would look for the "controls"-settings. Maybe you can change the input method for driving/bending/whatever.

If it really matters to you and you are not able to find any controls-changing settings you could eventually contact the developers. But it's probably simpler to just lookout for another game...